# Filter WordPress custom post types by taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, filtering, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have been struggling with this for a few days now and I seem to be no closer to a solution. I have been searching forums and tutorial sites, but have ended up more confused, as there seem to be a lot of ways and variations to achieve what I am looking for.

What I want to do is create a Custom Post Type archive that can be filtered by taxonomy terms based on the url string.

`_domain/products/_`

`_domain/products/taxonomy-term/_`

`_domain/products/taxonomy-term/product-1_`

So the taxonomy term will only display custom posts of that type.

I have got as far as this. Which seems to work for domain/products/taxonomy_term/product_1, but isn't picking up any archive templates.

```
    // define custom post types
    add_action( 'init', 'create_products' );
    function create_products() {

        register_post_type( 'products',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products/%product_cat%', 'with_front' => true ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5
            )
        );      
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0 );
    function create_my_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'product_cat',
        'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Product Categories',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
                'new_item_name' => "New Product Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' =>  array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => true ),
            'query_var' => true,
        )
    );
}

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'product_listing')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat'))
        $link = str_replace('%product_cat%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, have same problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/rewriting-a-custom-post-type-permalink-with-taxonomy-term

Comment: I've been through every, and I mean every, post on SO and WP.SE regarding the topic 'Custom Post Type and Taxonomy Archives' and have tried every little variation of each solution. Almost all of them say that if you set the post type with `'has_archive' => 'post_type_slug'` and `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post_type_slug/%tax_slug%' )'` and then set the taxonomy with `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post_type_slug' )` and include that little `post_type_link` filter, it should work. `.../post_type_slug/tax_term` throws a 404. And I do have a taxonomy-tax_slug.php file.

Comment: I think you should have read this by now, but, [here it is anyway](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)

Comment: can you tell me where you want to use? do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a conflict in naming. I had a post type with the same name as the taxonomy. That caused a conflict.

```
register_post_type( 'some_name' );
register_taxonomy( 'some_name' );
```

Rename the taxonomy to something unique.

```
register_taxonomy( 'some_tax_name' );
```